# Javadoc-like info boxes for visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, javadoc, comments

Are there any plugins/options/etc. that will show me this:

[image: Documentation Info Box]
when I hover over a C++ function/method name in visual studio 2010?

I've tried using visual assist X, but the info for the function is not indented, newlines are ignored, and terms like "return" and "Parameter" aren't bold or colored. The VS built-in XML comment stuff was even less readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have CodeRush/Refactor you can try the CR_Documenter plugin (use VS Extension Manager). It provides a new dockable window with such documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use SandCastle to integrate with the builtin help (F1). Its not as good as inline help like you get in your Eclipse screenshot, but you can hover over a type, press F1 and then you are there.

To do this, install Sandcastle and Sandcastle Help File Builder. Then in your Sandcastle Help File Builder project, make sure to tick the box for MSHelpViewer. This will generate documentation and a script you can run to integrate your custom documentation into the F1 help.